# Smoothify canvas draw

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have canvas draw app which dynamically changes lineWidth based on move speed. But it changes for whole part of line and transisions looks strange. Is there some simple way how to make the transision smooth? My code for dynamic lineWidth:

```
ctx.lineWidth = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt((previousX - previousY) * (previousX - currentX) + (previousY - currentY) * (previousY - currentY)) / 10);
```

Comment: You might get some ideas from http://perfectionkills.com/exploring-canvas-drawing-techniques

Answer (score 1):

One thought:

- Break your single line into smaller segments with incrementally changing lineWidths.
- Use context.lineJoin="round" to smooth the transition between those smaller segments.